# Angular 4 recaptcha - unexpected token <

Tags: angular, recaptcha

I'm completely new to Angular 4 and I have a task to implement reCAPTCHA. I'm following the example found on https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-recaptcha.

In app.module.ts I've added the following:

```
import { RecaptchaModule } from 'ng-recaptcha';
import { RecaptchaFormsModule } from 'ng-recaptcha/forms';
```

In @NgModule under 'imports' I've added this:

```
RecaptchaModule.forRoot(),
RecaptchaFormsModule
```

And when I run the app, I get this error in Chrome: "index.debug.html:33 Error: Unexpected token <"

What am I missing? I'm developing with Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: That's all I've added to the code in my original post. As soon as I add RecaptchaModule.forRoot(),
RecaptchaFormsModule in @NgModule under 'imports', the error shows up.

Comment: Try to run again 'ng serve'

Comment: Tried, didn't help. Same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if ur using in visual studio that means you are using .net + angular project in your system.config.js file use this

```
// SystemJS config file
 (function () {
 System.config({
paths: {
  'npm:': '/node_modules/',
},
map: {
  'ng-recaptcha': 'npm:ng-recaptcha',
},
packages: {
  'ng-recaptcha': { main: './index.js' },
},
 });
})();
```

Comment: Added ng-recaptcha under map and packages, it didn't help.

Comment: also add that packages also share the screenshot of that error

Comment: refer this you may get some idea https://plnkr.co/edit/JNVNl0WJl3bFuWtt2O9i?p=preview

Comment: UPDATE: you were right, I had to add 'ng-recaptcha' under "paths" and "packages". Now it's working!